# Detailed description of "Known IDE Packages" to safely remove unused packages

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, package

I'm doing some cleanup in my Delphi XE2 IDE in order to minimize the loaded packages and as a consequence of less things in the IDE try to make it a little more stable (man, how it crashes).

The main reason for doing this was that the Refactor shortcuts was conflictling with other tools I use and usually when I hit a refactor shortcut by mistake the IDE wold load a lot of stuff and crash with some .NET error, so I got rid of the Delphi default refactor functions.

To get rid of it I just removed the "refactoride160.bpl - Core Refactoring Package" from the registry and it did work.

But I noticed that there are a lot of other packages without description in the registry and I think it is interesting to know what are these packages in order to know what can be safely removed.

I know that there is some implications on removing the packages and it can be pointed out, but the main goal of this question is to understand better what is loaded on the IDE so I can tune it to my use.

Here are the entries from the registry, notice that there are a lot of Untitled packages, where can I find info about those? Which can be safely removed?

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Embarcadero\BDS\9.0\Known IDE Packages]
"C:\\Users\\Public\\Documents\\RAD Studio\\9.0\\Experts\\IDEFixPackStartup.bpl"="IDE Fix Pack Startup"
"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\SmartBear\\AQtime 7\\Bin\\AQtime7BDS9.bpl"="AQtime 7 IDE Package"
"$(BDS)\\Bin\\asmview160.bpl"="Assembly Browser Package"
"$(BDS)\\bin\\comptoolbar160.bpl"="Component Toolbar Package"
"$(BDS)\\Bin\\dbkdebugide160.bpl"="(Untitled)"
"$(BDS)\\Bin\\delphiwin32160.bpl"="Delphi Win32 Platform"
"$(BDS)\\Bin\\dotnetcoreide160.bpl"=".NET Core IDE Package"
"$(BDS)\\bin\\exceptiondiag160.bpl"="(Untitled)"
"$(BDS)\\bin\\fileexplorer160.bpl"="(Untitled)"
"$(BDS)\\bin\\historyide160.bpl"="(Untitled)"
"$(BDS)\\Bin\\htmlhelp2160.bpl"="HtmlHelp Viewer"
"$(BDS)\\bin\\idefilefilters160.bpl"="IDE File filters"
"$(BDS)\\bin\\plugview160.bpl"="Pluggable Tree View Package"
"$(BDS)\\Bin\\projecttargets160.bpl"="(Untitled)"
"$(BDS)\\Bin\\projpageide160.bpl"="Value Data: Project and template library package"
"$(BDS)\\Bin\\startpageide160.bpl"="Start Page IDE Package"
"$(BDS)\\Bin\\tlbview160.bpl"="TypeLibrary Browser Package"
"$(BDS)\\Bin\\codetemplates160.bpl"="(Untitled)"
"$(BDS)\\bin\\coreproide160.bpl"="Core IDE Pro Package"
"$(BDS)\\bin\\dbkdebugproide160.bpl"="(Untitled)"
"$(BDS)\\Bin\\profiledeployide160.bpl"="(Untitled)"
"$(BDS)\\Bin\\profilemgride160.bpl"="(Untitled)"
"$(BDS)\\bin\\refactoride160.bpl"="Core Refactoring Package"
"$(BDS)\\bin\\todoide160.bpl"="ToDo"
"$(BDS)\\Bin\\delphidotnetcore160.bpl"="(Untitled)"
"$(BDS)\\Bin\\DataExplorer160.bpl"="(Untitled)"
"$(BDS)\\Bin\\iteidew32160.bpl"="(Untitled)"
"$(BDS)\\bin\\htmlide160.bpl"="(Untitled)"
"$(BDS)\\Bin\\unittestide160.bpl"="(Untitled)"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Embarcadero\BDS\9.0\Known IDE Packages\Delphi]
"$(BDS)\\Bin\\delphicompro160.bpl"="(Untitled)"
"$(BDS)\\Bin\\delphide160.bpl"="Delphi Win32 IDE Personality"
"$(BDS)\\Bin\\delphipro160.bpl"="(Untitled)"
"$(BDS)\\Bin\\comcore160.bpl"="(Untitled)"
"$(BDS)\\Bin\\delphivclide160.bpl"="Delphi VCL Designer IDE Package"
"$(BDS)\\Bin\\vclmenudesigner160.bpl"="(Untitled)"
"$(BDS)\\Bin\\win32debugide160.bpl"="(Untitled)"
"$(BDS)\\Bin\\win32debugproide160.bpl"="(Untitled)"
"$(BDS)\\Bin\\delphicoment160.bpl"="(Untitled)"
"$(BDS)\\Bin\\delphierrorinsite160.bpl"="Delphi Error Insite Package"
"$(BDS)\\Bin\\delphicoreproide160.bpl"="(Untitled)"
"$(BDS)\\Bin\\delphiwin64160.bpl"="Delphi Win64 Platform"
"$(BDS)\\Bin\\win64debugide160.bpl"="(Untitled)"
"$(BDS)\\Bin\\TGIDE160.bpl"="Modeling IDE Integration"
```

Comment: I find the '(Untitled)' symptom rather confusing, in each installation case some turn out to be untitled at random. Anyway, the packages have their title/description in their version info resource. On W7, change extension to dll and see properties->details pane, or use a resource explorer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far I know a full list with the description of the Delphi IDE bpl's doesn't exist, but as a starting point (and following the [Sertac](https://stackoverflow.com/users/243614/sertac-akyuz) suggestion) you can extract the description of each bpl-file using the version info estructure. Using this info will give you some clues what the primary function of each bpl is.

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  IOUtils,
  Classes,
  Windows,
  SysUtils;


type
  TLangAndCP = record
    wLanguage : word;
    wCodePage : word;
    end;
  PLangAndCP = ^TLangAndCP;

Function GetFileDescription(const FileName : string) : string;
var
  dwLen     : integer;
  ZValue    : Cardinal;
  lpData    : PChar;
  Lang      : PLangAndCP;
  LangLen   : cardinal;
  SubBlock  : string;
  Value     : PChar;
  Len       : cardinal;
begin
  Result:='';
  dwLen:=GetFileVersionInfoSize(PChar(FileName),ZValue);
  if dwLen>0 then
  begin
    lpData:=AllocMem(dwLen);
    GetFileVersionInfo(PChar(FileName),0,dwLen,lpData);
    VerQueryValue(lpData,PChar('\\VarFileInfo\\Translation'),Pointer(Lang),LangLen);
    SubBlock:=Format('\\StringFileInfo\\%.4x%.4x\\%s',[Lang^.wLanguage,Lang^.wCodePage,'FileDescription']);
    VerQueryValue(lpData,PChar(SubBlock),Pointer(Value),Len);
    Result:=Value;
    FreeMem(lpData,dwLen);
  end;
end;

Var
  LFileName  : string;
  List       : TStrings;
begin
  try
   List:=TStringList.Create;
   try
     for LFileName  in TDirectory.GetFiles('C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\9.0\bin', '*.bpl') do
     List.Add(Format('%-30s %s',[ExtractFileName(LFileName), GetFileDescription(LFileName)]));
     List.SaveToFile('BplDesc.txt');
   finally
     List.Free;
   end;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

And this is the list of the bpl with the description.

```
adortl160.bpl                  Embarcadero ADO DB Component Package
applet160.bpl                  Embarcadero Control Panel Wizard
asmview160.bpl                 Assembly Viewer
AzureCloud160.bpl              DataSnap Azure Package
bcbcoment160.bpl               Embarcadero COM Enterprise Package for C++
bcbcompro160.bpl               Embarcadero COM Professional Package for C++
bcbcorba160.bpl                ACE/TAO CORBA IDE Package
bcbent160.bpl                  C++Builder Enterprise Integrated Development Environment
bcbfmxide160.bpl               Core BCB FMX IDE Package
bcbide160.bpl                  Core C++Builder Integrated Development Environment
bcbie160.bpl                   Embarcadero C++Builder Internet Explorer 6.0 Package
bcboffice2k160.bpl             Embarcadero C++Builder Office 2000 Components
bcbofficexp160.bpl             Embarcadero C++Builder Office XP Servers Package
bcbosx32160.bpl                C++Builder OSX32 Platform
bcbpro160.bpl                  C++Builder Professional Integrated Development Environment
bcbsmp160.bpl                  C++Builder Sample Components Package
bcbvclide160.bpl               Core BCB VCL IDE Package
bcbwin32160.bpl                C++Builder Win32 Platform
bdertl160.bpl                  Embarcadero BDE DB Component Package
bindcomp160.bpl                Embarcadero Component Package
bindcompfmx162.bpl             Embarcadero Component Package
bindcompvcl160.bpl             Embarcadero Component Package
bindengine160.bpl              Embarcadero Component Package
bindgraph160.bpl               Embarcadero Component Package
CloudService160.bpl            Cloud Service Package
codeguardide160.bpl            CodeGuard IDE Package
codetemplates160.bpl           Embarcadero Code Templates Manager
comcore160.bpl                 Embarcadero Core COM Professional Package
comentcore160.bpl              Embarcadero COM Core Enterprise Package
comptoolbar160.bpl             Embarcadero Component Toolbar
coreide160.bpl                 Core Integrated Development Environment
coreproide160.bpl              Core Professional Integrated Development Environment
CustomIPTransport160.bpl       Internet Protocol Custom Transport Package
DataExplorer160.bpl            Embarcadero Data Explorer Control Wrapper
DataSnapClient160.bpl          DataSnap Client Package
DataSnapCommon160.bpl          DataSnap Common Package
DataSnapConnectors160.bpl      DataSnap Connectors Package
DataSnapConnectorsFreePascal160.bpl DataSnap Mobile Connectors FreePascal Package
DataSnapIndy10ServerTransport160.bpl DataSnap Server Transport Package
DataSnapProviderClient160.bpl  DBX DataSnap Client Package
DataSnapServer160.bpl          DataSnap Server Package
dbexpress160.bpl               Embarcadero DBExpress Component Package
dbkdebugide160.bpl             DBK Debugger IDE Package
dbkdebugproide160.bpl          DBK Debugger Professional IDE Package
dbrtl160.bpl                   Embarcadero Database Component Package
dbtest.bpl                     DbTest Package
dbx160.bpl                     Embarcadero Database Explorer UI & engine package
dbxcds160.bpl                  Embarcadero Local DBX Client DataSet Component Package
DBXClientDriver160.bpl         DBXClientDriver Package
DbxCommonDriver160.bpl         DBXCommonDriver Package
DBXDb2Driver160.bpl            DBXDb2Driver Package
DBXFirebirdDriver160.bpl       DBXFirebirdDriver Package
DBXInformixDriver160.bpl       DBXInformixDriver Package
DBXInterBaseDriver160.bpl      DBXInterBaseDriver Package
DBXMSSQLDriver160.bpl          DBXMSSQLDriver Package
DBXMySqlDriver160.bpl          DBXMySQLDriver Package
DBXOdbcDriver160.bpl           DBXOdbcDriver Package
DBXOracleDriver160.bpl         DBXOracleDriver Package
DBXSybaseASADriver160.bpl      DBXSybaseASADriver Package
DBXSybaseASEDriver160.bpl      DBXSybaseASEDriver Package
dcl31w160.bpl                  Embarcadero Windows 3.1 Components
dclact160.bpl                  Embarcadero ActionBar Components
dclado160.bpl                  Embarcadero ADO DB Components
dclbcbsmp160.bpl               C++Builder Design Time Sample Components Package
dclbde160.bpl                  Embarcadero BDE DB Components
dclbindcomp160.bpl             Embarcadero LiveBindings Components
dclbindcompfmx160.bpl          Embarcadero LiveBindings Components FireMonkey
dclbindcompvcl160.bpl          Embarcadero LiveBindings Components VCL
dclCloudService160.bpl         Cloud Service Design Package
dclDataSnapClient160.bpl       DataSnap Client Design Package
dclDataSnapCommon160.bpl       DataSnap Common Design Package
dclDataSnapConnectors160.bpl   DataSnap Connectors Design Package
dclDataSnapIndy10ServerTransport160.bpl DataSnap Server Transport Design Package
dclDataSnapProviderClient160.bpl DataSnap Provider Client Design Package
dclDataSnapServer160.bpl       DataSnap Server Design Package
dcldb160.bpl                   Embarcadero Database Components
dcldbx160.bpl                  Embarcadero DBExpress Components
dcldbxcds160.bpl               Embarcadero Local DBX ClientDataSet Components
dclDBXDrivers160.bpl           dbExpress Drivers Design Package
dclDBXDriversEnt160.bpl        dbExpress Enterprise Drivers Design Package
dclDBXDriversInt160.bpl        dbExpress Drivers Int Design Package
dclemacsedit160.bpl            Embarcadero EMACS Keybindings Example Package
dclExpertsCreators160.bpl      Embarcadero Experts Creators Design Package
dclExpertsUI160.bpl            Embarcadero Experts UI Design Package
dclfmistd160.bpl               Embarcadero FMI Standard Components
dclfmxstd160.bpl               Embarcadero FMX Standard Components
dclib160.bpl                   Interbase Express Design Package
dclIBXLegacy160.bpl            Legacy Interbase Express Design Package
dclie160.bpl                   Delphi-32 Development Environment
dclIndyCore160.bpl             Internet Direct (Indy) 10.5.7 Core Design-Time Package for Delphi
dclIndyProtocols160.bpl        Internet Direct (Indy) 10.5.7 Protocols Design-Time Package for Delphi
dclIPIndyImpl160.bpl           Embarcadero IP Indy Abstraction Implementation
dclmcn160.bpl                  Embarcadero Midas Components
dclmid160.bpl                  Embarcadero Local Provider Components
dclmlwiz160.bpl                IDE Wizards for Markup Languages
dclnet160.bpl                  Embarcadero Internet Components
dcloffice2010160.bpl           Embarcadero Sample ActiveX Server Components
dcloffice2K160.bpl             Embarcadero Sample ActiveX Server Components
dclofficexp160.bpl             Embarcadero Sample ActiveX Server Components
dclribbon160.bpl               Embarcadero ActionBar Components
dclsmp160.bpl                  Delphi Sample Components
dclsmpedit160.bpl              Embarcadero Sample Editor Enhancments Package
dclsoap160.bpl                 Embarcadero Soap Components
dclsockets160.bpl              Embarcadero Socket Component
dclstd160.bpl                  Embarcadero Standard Components
dcltouch160.bpl                Embarcadero Touch Components
dclwbm160.bpl                  Embarcadero Web Midas Components Designers
dclwebsnap160.bpl              Embarcadero WebSnap Design Package
dclWindowsAzureManagement160.bpl Windows Azure Management Design Package
delphicoment160.bpl            Embarcadero COM Enterprise Package for Delphi
delphicompro160.bpl            Embarcadero COM Professional Package for Delphi
delphicoreide160.bpl           Delphi Core Integrated Development Environment
delphicoreproide160.bpl        Delphi Core Professional Integrated Development Environment
delphide160.bpl                Core Delphi Integrated Development Environment
delphidotnetcore160.bpl        Delphi for .NET IDE Core Package
delphierrorinsite160.bpl       Delphi Error Insite Package
delphifmiide160.bpl            Core Delphi FMI IDE Package
delphifmxide160.bpl            Core Delphi FMX IDE Package
delphiosx32160.bpl             Delphi OSX32 Platform
delphipro160.bpl               Delphi Professional Integrated Development Environment
delphivclide160.bpl            Core Delphi VCL IDE Package
delphiwin32160.bpl             Delphi Win32 Platform
delphiwin64160.bpl             Delphi Win64 Platform
designide160.bpl               Embarcadero IDE Designer Package
dfm160.bpl                     Embarcadero Integrated Translation Environment
DotnetCoreAssemblies160.bpl    Contains the DOTNET Core Assemblies Package
dotnetcoreide160.bpl           Core .NET Integrated Development Environment
dsnap160.bpl                   Embarcadero Local Provider Component Package
dsnapcon160.bpl                Embarcadero MIDAS Component Package
EMUVCLHelper160.bpl            Embarcadero EMUVCL Helper Runtime Support
exceptiondiag160.bpl           Exception Diagnostics for Integrated Development Environment
ExpertsCreators160.bpl         Experts Creators Package
ExpertsUI160.bpl               Embarcadero Experts UI Package
fileexplorer160.bpl            Embarcadero IDE File Explorer
fmi162.bpl                     Embarcadero Component Package
fmidesigner160.bpl             Embarcadero IDE FMX Designer Package
fmx162.bpl                     Embarcadero Component Package
fmxase162.bpl                  Embarcadero Component Package
fmxdae162.bpl                  Embarcadero Component Package
fmxdesigner160.bpl             Embarcadero IDE FMX Designer Package
fmxobj162.bpl                  Embarcadero Component Package
historyide160.bpl              Embarcadero IDE File History Manager
htmide160.bpl                  HTML Designer
htmldlgs160.bpl                HTML Designer Dialogs
htmlhelp2160.bpl               HtmlHelp2
htmlide160.bpl                 HTML Integrated Development Environment Package
ibevnt160.bpl                  Delphi Interbase Component Package
ibxpress160.bpl                Interbase Express Run-time Package
idefilefilters160.bpl          IDE File Filters
IndyCore160.bpl                Internet Direct (Indy) 10.5.7 Core Run-Time Package for Delphi
IndyProtocols160.bpl           Internet Direct (Indy) 10.5.7 Protocols Run-Time Package for Delphi
IndySystem160.bpl              Internet Direct (Indy) 10.5.7 - System Run-Time Package for Delphi
inet160.bpl                    Embarcadero Internet Component Package
inetdb160.bpl                  Embarcadero Internet DB Component Package
inetdbbde160.bpl               Embarcadero Internet DB BDE Component Package
inetdbxpress160.bpl            Embarcadero Internet DBxpress Component Package
IPIndyImpl160.bpl              IP Indy Implementation Package
itecore160.bpl                 Embarcadero Integrated Translation Environment
iteide160.bpl                  Embarcadero Integrated Translation Environment
iteidebcb160.bpl               Embarcadero Integrated Translation Environment for Win32
iteidew32160.bpl               Embarcadero Integrated Translation Environment for Win32
macosxdebugide160.bpl          Mac OSX Debugger IDE Package
mlcc160.bpl                    Markup Code Completion
Office2010rt160.bpl            Embarcadero Sample ActiveX Server Components
Office2K160.bpl                Embarcadero Sample ActiveX Server Components
officeXPrt160.bpl              Embarcadero Sample ActiveX Server Components
optpchwizard160.bpl            CodeGear Precompiled Header Wizard Package
paclientcore160.bpl            Platform Assistant Client Core Package
plugview160.bpl                Pluggable Tree View
profiledeployide160.bpl        Profile Deployment IDE Package
profilemgride160.bpl           Profile Manager IDE Package
projecttargets160.bpl          Embarcadero MSBuild Targets File Handler
projpageide160.bpl             Project Page Options
rc160.bpl                      Embarcadero Integrated Translation Environment
refactoride160.bpl             Refactoring IDE Package
rtl160.bpl                     Embarcadero Component Package
samplevisualizers160.bpl       CodeGear Sample Debug Visualizers
soaprtl160.bpl                 Embarcadero SOAP Runtime Support
startpageide160.bpl            Embarcadero Start Page IDE Package
stride160.bpl                  String Resource Editor IDE Package
svn160.bpl                     Embarcadero Subverion integration
svnide160.bpl                  Embarcadero Subverion IDE Integration
svnui160.bpl                   Embarcadero Subverion UI Integration
tgide160.bpl                   UML Modeling Integration
tlbview160.bpl                 Type Library Viewer
tlib160.bpl                    Embarcadero Type Library Engine Package
todoide160.bpl                 Embarcadero IDE TODO Manager
vcl160.bpl                     Embarcadero Component Package
vclactnband160.bpl             Embarcadero Component Package
vcldb160.bpl                   Embarcadero Database Component Package
vcldbx160.bpl                  Embarcadero Extended DB Component Package
vcldesigner160.bpl             Embarcadero IDE VCL Designer Package
vcldsnap160.bpl                Embarcadero VCL DataSnap Component Package
vclhie160.bpl                  Browser Hosting Support
vclib160.bpl                   Interbase Express VCL Run-time Package
vclide160.bpl                  Integrated Development Environment Specific Components
vclie160.bpl                   WebBrowser Components
vclimg160.bpl                  Embarcadero Imaging Package
vclmenudesigner160.bpl         Embarcadero IDE Designer Package
vclribbon160.bpl               Embarcadero Component Package
vclshlctrls160.bpl             CodeGear Win32 Shell Controls
vclsmp160.bpl                  Delphi Sample Component Package
vcltouch160.bpl                Embarcadero Component Package
vclx160.bpl                    Embarcadero Extended Component Package
webdsnap160.bpl                Embarcadero Web Midas Components
websnap160.bpl                 Embarcadero WebSnap Component Package
win32debugide160.bpl           Win32 Native Code Debugger IDE Package
win32debugproide160.bpl        Win32 Native Code Debugger IDE Professional Package
win64debugide160.bpl           Win64 Native Code Debugger IDE Package
xmlrtl160.bpl                  Embarcadero XML Component Package
```

Comment: Same idea ;o) (you code faster or read the question before ;o)

Answer (score 4):

***Safely*** depends on what you are using or not...

Here is the list... quickly generated with Delphi (I took the Description as explained by Sertac in the first comment...)

```
'adortl160': Embarcadero ADO DB Component Package
'applet160': Embarcadero Control Panel Wizard
'asmview160': Assembly Viewer
'AzureCloud160': DataSnap Azure Package
'bdertl160': Embarcadero BDE DB Component Package
'bindcomp160': Embarcadero Component Package
'bindcompfmx162': Embarcadero Component Package
'bindcompvcl160': Embarcadero Component Package
'bindengine160': Embarcadero Component Package
'bindgraph160': Embarcadero Component Package
'CloudService160': Cloud Service Package
'codetemplates160': Embarcadero Code Templates Manager
'comcore160': Embarcadero Core COM Professional Package
'comentcore160': Embarcadero COM Core Enterprise Package
'comptoolbar160': Embarcadero Component Toolbar
'coreide160': Core Integrated Development Environment
'coreproide160': Core Professional Integrated Development Environment
'CustomIPTransport160': Internet Protocol Custom Transport Package
'DataExplorer160': Embarcadero Data Explorer Control Wrapper
'DataSnapClient160': DataSnap Client Package
'DataSnapCommon160': DataSnap Common Package
'DataSnapConnectors160': DataSnap Connectors Package
'DataSnapConnectorsFreePascal160': DataSnap Mobile Connectors FreePascal Package
'DataSnapIndy10ServerTransport160': DataSnap Server Transport Package
'DataSnapProviderClient160': DBX DataSnap Client Package
'DataSnapServer160': DataSnap Server Package
'dbexpress160': Embarcadero DBExpress Component Package
'dbkdebugide160': DBK Debugger IDE Package
'dbkdebugproide160': DBK Debugger Professional IDE Package
'dbrtl160': Embarcadero Database Component Package
'dbtest': DbTest Package
'dbx160': Embarcadero Database Explorer UI & engine package
'dbxcds160': Embarcadero Local DBX Client DataSet Component Package
'DBXClientDriver160': DBXClientDriver Package
'DbxCommonDriver160': DBXCommonDriver Package
'DBXDb2Driver160': DBXDb2Driver Package
'DBXFirebirdDriver160': DBXFirebirdDriver Package
'DBXInformixDriver160': DBXInformixDriver Package
'DBXInterBaseDriver160': DBXInterBaseDriver Package
'DBXMSSQLDriver160': DBXMSSQLDriver Package
'DBXMySqlDriver160': DBXMySQLDriver Package
'DBXOdbcDriver160': DBXOdbcDriver Package
'DBXOracleDriver160': DBXOracleDriver Package
'DBXSybaseASADriver160': DBXSybaseASADriver Package
'DBXSybaseASEDriver160': DBXSybaseASEDriver Package
'dcl31w160': Embarcadero Windows 3.1 Components
'dclact160': Embarcadero ActionBar Components
'dclado160': Embarcadero ADO DB Components
'dclbde160': Embarcadero BDE DB Components
'dclbindcomp160': Embarcadero LiveBindings Components
'dclbindcompfmx160': Embarcadero LiveBindings Components FireMonkey
'dclbindcompvcl160': Embarcadero LiveBindings Components VCL
'dclCloudService160': Cloud Service Design Package
'dclDataSnapClient160': DataSnap Client Design Package
'dclDataSnapCommon160': DataSnap Common Design Package
'dclDataSnapConnectors160': DataSnap Connectors Design Package
'dclDataSnapIndy10ServerTransport160': DataSnap Server Transport Design Package
'dclDataSnapProviderClient160': DataSnap Provider Client Design Package
'dclDataSnapServer160': DataSnap Server Design Package
'dcldb160': Embarcadero Database Components
'dcldbx160': Embarcadero DBExpress Components
'dcldbxcds160': Embarcadero Local DBX ClientDataSet Components
'dclDBXDrivers160': dbExpress Drivers Design Package
'dclDBXDriversEnt160': dbExpress Enterprise Drivers Design Package
'dclDBXDriversInt160': dbExpress Drivers Int Design Package
'dclemacsedit160': Embarcadero EMACS Keybindings Example Package
'dclExpertsCreators160': Embarcadero Experts Creators Design Package
'dclExpertsUI160': Embarcadero Experts UI Design Package
'dclfmistd160': Embarcadero FMI Standard Components
'dclfmxstd160': Embarcadero FMX Standard Components
'dclFMXtee9160': TeeChart for FMX
'dclib160': Interbase Express Design Package
'dclIBXLegacy160': Legacy Interbase Express Design Package
'dclie160': Delphi-32 Development Environment
'dclIndyCore160': Internet Direct (Indy) 10.5.7 Core Design-Time Package for Delphi
'dclIndyProtocols160': Internet Direct (Indy) 10.5.7 Protocols Design-Time Package for Delphi
'dclIntraweb_120_160': IntraWeb Components for Delphi
'dclIPIndyImpl160': Embarcadero IP Indy Abstraction Implementation
'dclmcn160': Embarcadero Midas Components
'dclmid160': Embarcadero Local Provider Components
'dclmlwiz160': IDE Wizards for Markup Languages
'dclnet160': Embarcadero Internet Components
'dcloffice2010160': Embarcadero Sample ActiveX Server Components
'dcloffice2K160': Embarcadero Sample ActiveX Server Components
'dclofficexp160': Embarcadero Sample ActiveX Server Components
'dclribbon160': Embarcadero ActionBar Components
'dclsmp160': Delphi Sample Components
'dclsmpedit160': Embarcadero Sample Editor Enhancments Package
'dclsoap160': Embarcadero Soap Components
'dclsockets160': Embarcadero Socket Component
'dclstd160': Embarcadero Standard Components
'dcltee9160': TeeChart Pro Designtime Package
'dcltouch160': Embarcadero Touch Components
'dclwbm160': Embarcadero Web Midas Components Designers
'dclwebsnap160': Embarcadero WebSnap Design Package
'dclWindowsAzureManagement160': Windows Azure Management Design Package
'delphicoment160': Embarcadero COM Enterprise Package for Delphi
'delphicompro160': Embarcadero COM Professional Package for Delphi
'delphicoreide160': Delphi Core Integrated Development Environment
'delphicoreproide160': Delphi Core Professional Integrated Development Environment
'delphide160': Core Delphi Integrated Development Environment
'delphidotnetcore160': Delphi for .NET IDE Core Package
'delphierrorinsite160': Delphi Error Insite Package
'delphifmiide160': Core Delphi FMI IDE Package
'delphifmxide160': Core Delphi FMX IDE Package
'delphiosx32160': Delphi OSX32 Platform
'delphipro160': Delphi Professional Integrated Development Environment
'delphivclide160': Core Delphi VCL IDE Package
'delphiwin32160': Delphi Win32 Platform
'delphiwin64160': Delphi Win64 Platform
'designide160': Embarcadero IDE Designer Package
'dfm160': Embarcadero Integrated Translation Environment
'DotnetCoreAssemblies160': Contains the DOTNET Core Assemblies Package
'dotnetcoreide160': Core .NET Integrated Development Environment
'dsnap160': Embarcadero Local Provider Component Package
'dsnapcon160': Embarcadero MIDAS Component Package
'dunitrtl160': DUnit Runtime Support
'EMUVCLHelper160': Embarcadero EMUVCL Helper Runtime Support
'exceptiondiag160': Exception Diagnostics for Integrated Development Environment
'ExpertsCreators160': Experts Creators Package
'ExpertsUI160': Embarcadero Experts UI Package
'fileexplorer160': Embarcadero IDE File Explorer
'fmi162': Embarcadero Component Package
'fmidesigner160': Embarcadero IDE FMX Designer Package
'fmx162': Embarcadero Component Package
'fmxase162': Embarcadero Component Package
'fmxdae162': Embarcadero Component Package
'fmxdesigner160': Embarcadero IDE FMX Designer Package
'fmxobj162': Embarcadero Component Package
'FMXtee9160': TeeChart 9
'FMXteeui9160': TeeChart 9
'historyide160': Embarcadero IDE File History Manager
'htmide160': HTML Designer
'htmldlgs160': HTML Designer Dialogs
'htmlhelp2160': HtmlHelp2
'htmlide160': HTML Integrated Development Environment Package
'ibevnt160': Delphi Interbase Component Package
'ibxpress160': Interbase Express Run-time Package
'idefilefilters160': IDE File Filters
'IndyCore160': Internet Direct (Indy) 10.5.7 Core Run-Time Package for Delphi
'IndyProtocols160': Internet Direct (Indy) 10.5.7 Protocols Run-Time Package for Delphi
'IndySystem160': Internet Direct (Indy) 10.5.7 - System Run-Time Package for Delphi
'inet160': Embarcadero Internet Component Package
'inetdb160': Embarcadero Internet DB Component Package
'inetdbbde160': Embarcadero Internet DB BDE Component Package
'inetdbxpress160': Embarcadero Internet DBxpress Component Package
'Intraweb_120_160': IntraWeb for Delphi
'IntrawebDB_120_160': IntraWeb DB components for Delphi
'IPIndyImpl160': IP Indy Implementation Package
'itecore160': Embarcadero Integrated Translation Environment
'iteide160': Embarcadero Integrated Translation Environment
'iteidew32160': Embarcadero Integrated Translation Environment for Win32
'macosxdebugide160': Mac OSX Debugger IDE Package
'mlcc160': Markup Code Completion
'Office2010rt160': Embarcadero Sample ActiveX Server Components
'Office2K160': Embarcadero Sample ActiveX Server Components
'officeXPrt160': Embarcadero Sample ActiveX Server Components
'paclientcore160': Platform Assistant Client Core Package
'plugview160': Pluggable Tree View
'profiledeployide160': Profile Deployment IDE Package
'profilemgride160': Profile Manager IDE Package
'projecttargets160': Embarcadero MSBuild Targets File Handler
'projpageide160': Project Page Options
'rc160': Embarcadero Integrated Translation Environment
'refactoride160': Refactoring IDE Package
'rtl160': Embarcadero Component Package
'samplevisualizers160': CodeGear Sample Debug Visualizers
'soaprtl160': Embarcadero SOAP Runtime Support
'startpageide160': Embarcadero Start Page IDE Package
'stride160': String Resource Editor IDE Package
'svn160': Embarcadero Subverion integration
'svnide160': Embarcadero Subverion IDE Integration
'svnui160': Embarcadero Subverion UI Integration
'tee9160': TeeChart 9
'teedb9160': TeeChart 9
'teeui9160': TeeChart 9
'tgide160': UML Modeling Integration
'tlbview160': Type Library Viewer
'tlib160': Embarcadero Type Library Engine Package
'todoide160': Embarcadero IDE TODO Manager
'unittestide160': Unit Testing IDE Package
'vcl160': Embarcadero Component Package
'vclactnband160': Embarcadero Component Package
'vcldb160': Embarcadero Database Component Package
'vcldbx160': Embarcadero Extended DB Component Package
'vcldesigner160': Embarcadero IDE VCL Designer Package
'vcldsnap160': Embarcadero VCL DataSnap Component Package
'vclhie160': Browser Hosting Support
'vclib160': Interbase Express VCL Run-time Package
'vclide160': Integrated Development Environment Specific Components
'vclie160': WebBrowser Components
'vclimg160': Embarcadero Imaging Package
'vclmenudesigner160': Embarcadero IDE Designer Package
'vclribbon160': Embarcadero Component Package
'vclshlctrls160': CodeGear Win32 Shell Controls
'vclsmp160': Delphi Sample Component Package
'vcltouch160': Embarcadero Component Package
'vclx160': Embarcadero Extended Component Package
'webdsnap160': Embarcadero Web Midas Components
'websnap160': Embarcadero WebSnap Component Package
'win32debugide160': Win32 Native Code Debugger IDE Package
'win32debugproide160': Win32 Native Code Debugger IDE Professional Package
'win64debugide160': Win64 Native Code Debugger IDE Package
'xmlrtl160': Embarcadero XML Component Package
```

And if you need it... my source code:

```
unit main;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.ComCtrls, System.IOUtils, System.Types, Vcl.Clipbrd;

type
  TfrmMain = class(TForm)
    lvBPLs: TListView;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  frmMain: TfrmMain;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

uses uWxPlatform;

procedure TfrmMain.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
//  dir   : TDirectory;
  files: TStringDynArray;
  bpl  : string;
  fvi  : TFileVersionInfo;
  sl   : TStringList;
begin
  sl := TStringList.Create;
  try
    files := TDirectory.GetFiles('C:\Program Files (x86)\RAD Studio\9.0\bin', '*.bpl');
    for bpl in files do
    begin
      with lvBPLs.Items.Add do
      begin
        Caption := ChangeFileExt(ExtractFileName(bpl), '');
        TMisc.GetAppVersionInfo(bpl, fvi);
        SubItems.Add(fvi.fFileDescription);
        sl.Add('''' + Caption + ''': ' + fvi.fFileDescription);
      end;
    end;
    sl.Sort;
    Clipboard.AsText := sl.Text;
  finally
    sl.Free;
  end;
end;

end.
```

Comment: Oups... a unit where I merge some of functions which are cross-platform (to use with FireMonkey...) [Source code is available in this post](http://blogs.wittwer.fr/whiler/2012/04/06/fonctions-delphi/)

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anybody is interested:
I wrote a tool to disable Known IDE Packages by moving the entries to a different registry key, so they can be enabled again if there is a problem.
This tool also reads the description and additional information from the package (using SysUtils.GetPackageDescription and SysUtils.GetPackageInfo) as well as from the version information.

[image]

It works for Delphi 6 to 10.4 and could probably easily adapted to work with older versions if need arises.

It's available from [OSDN](https://osdn.net/projects/knownidepackagesmanager/)